# Parsing haskell-like lambda in antlr

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to parse a haskell-like language using antlr4 and I'm stuck with lambdas. In haskell, lambdas can be mixed with operators. So, given operators `>>=`, `+` and lambda syntax `'\\' args* '->' expr`, the following expression is [valid](https://repl.it/@AmatanHead/Haskell-lambda):

```
a >>= \a -> b >>= \b -> Just(a + b)
```

and it should be parsed into the following AST:

```
  >>=
 /   \
a     ->
     /  \
    a   >>=
       /   \
      b    ->
          /  \
         b   Just
              |
              +
             / \
            a   b
```

So I can think of two ways of structuring grammar for this kind of syntax.

The first is to put lambda expression into the top expression rule, among with `if`s and other syntax constructs:

```
grammar Test;

root
    : expr0 EOF
    ;

expr0
    : '\\' ID '->' expr0
    | expr1
    ;

expr1
    : expr2 ('>>=' expr2)*
    ;

expr2
    : expr3 ('+' expr3)*
    ;

expr3
    : '(' expr0 ')'
    | ID ('(' expr0 ')')?
    ;
```

This grammar cannot parse the above expression. It is required to add parens around lambda: `a >>= (\a -> b >>= (\b -> Just(a + b)))`. While I understand why parens are required, this behaviour is pretty inconvenient.

The second approach would be to put lambda to the last expression rule, among with literals and nested expressions:

```
grammar Test;

root
    : expr0 EOF
    ;

expr0
    : expr1 ('>>=' expr1)*
    ;

expr1
    : expr2 ('+' expr2)*
    ;

expr2
    : '(' expr0 ')'
    | ID ('(' expr0 ')')?
    | '\\' ID '->' expr0
    ;
```

This grammar accepts my expression, however, it contains ambiguity because `a >>= \a -> b >>= \b -> Just(a + b)` can be parsed either as `a >>= \a -> (b >>= \b) -> Just(a + b)` or as `a >>= \a -> (b >>= \b -> Just(a + b))`.

So my question is, how to implement this kind of grammar properly?

Comment: Are there any practical issues with your second approach? ANTLR does parse it the way you want it to, doesn't it?

Comment: @sepp2k yes but the grammar is ambiguous which means it takes more time and lookahead to parse (the grammar becomes `LL*` while I'd like to keep it `LLk`).